# Interface with Multiple definitions C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, enums

I have a couple basic message Enums that I am putting into an interface to control them.  However as I do this, I need to support the Legacy messages, while still adding the new ones in.  What is the best way to do this?

This is the general idea of the `Msg` interface:

```
public interface Msg
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ID of the message
    /// </summary>
    Legacy_Msgs MessageId { get; }
    //New_Msgs MessageId { get; }    // How implement use this?

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the message to a byte array representation
    /// </summary>
    byte[] MsgBytes { get; }
}
```

However what I question is does it make more sense to have a new interface for the `New_Msgs`, that inherits `Msg` and overrides the `MessageId`, or does it make more sense from an efficiency standpoint to just have a completely new `NewMsg` interface for the `New_Msg` enum.
I realize both solutions could work, but I am wondering as another developer looking at that kind of solution, what makes more sense?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces cannot override, but you can add new items to the contract via the interface.

If the behavior is going to change between implementations such that they are not backward compatible, then you should make a completely new interface/implementation with no relationship to the old one, as someone could create an instance of the new one, and pass it to a consumer expecting the old one.

A single implementation could implement both interfaces to maintain as much compatability as possible. If the interfaces have an overlap of the members, then you could use explicit interface implementation to maintain both interfaces together.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of structure might give you more flexibility, while keeping your `IMsg` contract consistent for consumers.

```
// the following three MsgId contracts don't have to be contracts at all (the actual types can be specified in generic IMsg directly), but if one ID type is wildly different in nature than the other, an interface such as this might make sense.

public interface IMsgId
{
 // ?
}

public interface INewMsgId : IMsgId
{
}

public interface ILegacyMsgId : IMsgId
{
}

public interface IMsg<out TId>
   where TId : IMsgId
{
   TId MessageId { get; }

   byte[] MsgBytes { get; }
}

// if it is sensible, you can use the following interfaces to create definitive new and legacy message contracts

public interface INewMsg : IMsg<INewMsgId>
{
}

public interface ILegacyMsg : IMsg<ILegacyMsgId>
{
}
```

Here's an example of implementation:

```
public class LegacyMsgId : ILegacyMsgId
{
    public LegacyMsgId(int id)
    {
      Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Legacy Message #" + Id;
    }
}

public class NewMsgId : INewMsgId
{
    public NewMsgId(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "New Message #" + Id;
    }
}

public class NewMsg : INewMsg
{
    public NewMsg(int id)
    {
        MessageId = new NewMsgId(id);
    }

    public NewMsgId MessageId { get; private set; }

    INewMsgId IMsg<INewMsgId>.MessageId { get { return MessageId; } }

    public byte[] MsgBytes { get; private set; }
}

public class LegacyMsg : ILegacyMsg
{
    public LegacyMsg(int id)
    {
        MessageId = new LegacyMsgId(id);
    }

    public LegacyMsgId MessageId { get; private set; }

    ILegacyMsgId IMsg<ILegacyMsgId>.MessageId { get { return MessageId; } }

    public byte[] MsgBytes { get; private set; }
}
```

And usage:

```
var messages = new List<IMsg<IMsgId>>();
messages.Add(new NewMsg(20));
messages.Add(new LegacyMsg(11));

foreach(var message in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.MessageId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However what I question is does it make more sense to have a new interface for the New_Msgs, that inherits Msg and overrides the MessageId

You can't have an interface with `override`s, you can however use `new` but that implies that both have the same signature which is not the case here.

If you're defining new functionality, that is not backwards compatible with the previous interface then I would suggest something like `interface Msg2` which is not related (ie. does not inherit) to `interface Msg`.  Since a class can implement multiple interfaces, then your actual implementation can handle both interface implementations while keeping the definitions separate, and thus allowing any future code the choice of whether or not to handle the legacy implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is using this interface (I think either solution should be fine)  I would suggest using the "Obsolete" tag to alert other developers about the update.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44(v=vs.80).aspx

```
public interface INewMsgId : IMsgId
{
}

[System.Obsolete("use interface INewMsgId ")]
public interface ILegacyMsgId : IMsgId
{
{
```

Comment: Others will be using it, however unfortunately the Legacy is not obsolete, they want to drag it on and have it fully supported until further notice... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with this in several ways:

1. You can refactor your code to [replace type code with subclasses](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-subclasses). Enums are basically plain constants with a tiny bit of type safety, and are not suitable for OOP and versioning. In C#, they cannot be extended:

   ```
   public interface IMsg
   {
       // let `MessageType` be a class
       MessageType Type { get; }
       byte[] Data { get; }
   }
   ```
2. Or, you can use plain int IDs, and separate the actual meaning behind specific MessageIDs from the simple object that contains data.

   ```
   // let Msg be a dumb data object
   public interface IMsg
   {
       int Id { get; }
       byte[] Data { get; }
   }

   // and then keep their types weakly-typed
   private readonly Dictionary<int, String> MessageNames;

   // and you can also provide various type-based functionality
   // during runtime
   private readonly Dictionary<int, IParser> Parsers;
   ```

As a side note, it's a .NET naming conventions to prepend a capital `I` to all interface names.